# Format Dates in R to show only the year

Tags: r, date, format

I have got a date in R having class "factor". I want to take the year from the data. Please advice

Example data:

```
S No. Customer Month           amount
1       A       01-01-2020      1500
2       B       23-02-2020      2000
3       C       15-03-2020      2500
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you show us what you have tried so far? Do not hesitate to show us the error messages you get so we can help you more specifically.

Answer (score 0):

`data$Month <- as.character(data$Month)
data$Month <- as.Date(data$Month,"%d-%m-%Y")
data$Year <- year(data$Month)`

Comment: Thanks for your post. Would it be possible for you to add a few explanation  with your answer? It would be great if you could also display the results your output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```r
df <- read.table(text="S 'No. Customer' Month           amount
1       A       01-01-2020      1500
2       B       23-02-2020      2000
3       C       15-03-2020      2500", header = TRUE)

df$year <- format(as.Date(df$Month, "%d-%m-%Y"), "%Y")
df
#>   S No..Customer      Month amount year
#> 1 1            A 01-01-2020   1500 2020
#> 2 2            B 23-02-2020   2000 2020
#> 3 3            C 15-03-2020   2500 2020
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>